# Failed to connect to MySQL database from command-line only

Tags: linux, bash, mysql

We have a AWS MySQL instance, and it works fine. We can connect to it with PHP/Doctrine, etc. but as soon as we try to connect using a bash script, it fails.

I have narrowed the problem to the password, that some characters somehow caue the command to fail. The original password did contain the `&` character, so I changed the password to something without that character. Alas, it still fails.

The script I have looks like this :

```
DB_HOST="<aws instance address>"
DB_USER="<username>"
DB_PASS="<password>"
DB_NAME="<database>"

mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME
```

So, if a password contains characters such as `$`, `*`, `+`,`&`, etc. how would I use this password given the script above? Would I need to escape the characters?

Comment: [Double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: Something like this doesnt work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663630/mysql-command-line-password-with-special-characters-is-not-working

Comment: None of these things work, but @mazaneicha link discouraged me from continuing head butting this issue. I change the password to contain only letters and numbers.and it solved it.